# Program throwing an exception after I check for the exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, heap, binary-tree

I must be missing something *very* simple because this is blowing my mind!

I am trying to implement a Heap using a CompleteBinaryTree (which is implemented using an array). This CompleteBinaryTree is an array of `Position<T>` where each `Position` holds an element. I am writing the `add(T t)` method for the Heap, where `t` is inserted into the next free position of the CompleteBinaryTree, and then an upheap process is performed until the CompleteBinaryTree is ordered. Here is the method:

```
    private CompleteBinaryTree<T> tree = new CompleteBinaryTree<T>();
    private Position<T> entry = null;

    public void add(T t) {
        entry = tree.add(t);

        if (entry.equals(tree.root())) {
            return;
        }

        //continue to swap inserted element with its parent   
        //while it is smaller than its parent
        while (entry.element().compareTo(tree.parent(entry).element()) < 0) {
            Position<T> parent = tree.parent(entry);
            Position<T> temp = entry;
            entry = parent;
            parent = temp;
        }
    }
```

The first element is added fine into the Heap, but when I try to add the second element, an `InvalidPositionException` is thrown at the `while()` line. This is where the exeption is being thrown from inside the CompleteBinaryTree class:

```
    public Position<T> parent(Position<T> p) {
        if (p == root()) throw new InvalidPositionException();

        return array[((ArrayPosition) p).index/2];
    }
```

And here are the two other methods used from `CompleteBinaryTree`:

```
    public Position<T> root() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new InvalidPositionException();
        return array[1];
    }

    public Position<T> add(T t) {
        if (last == array.length) {
            // extend array
            ArrayPosition[] temp = (ArrayPosition[]) new Object[array.length*2];
            for (int i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = array[i];
            }
            array = temp;
        }

        array[last] = new ArrayPosition(last, t);
        return array[last++];
    }
```

How am I getting an exception thrown because `p == root()`, when I first check if p is the root?

**EDIT**

Here is the CompleteBinaryTree `toString()`, which is returned by the Heap `toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 1; i < last; i++) {
        buf.append(" ").append(array[i]);
    }

    return buf.toString();      
}
```

Comment: `root()` is probably throwing.

Comment: but before the exception is thrown, the method returns if `entry` is the root, but then the exception is thrown because `entry` is the root?

Comment: Did you debug? Was exception raised on `if (p == root())` or `if (isEmpty())`, better that you move `throw new InvalidPositionException();` to new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I getting an exception thrown because p == root(), when I first check if p is the root?

But you *do not* check every `tree.parent()` argument to see whether it is root.  You check only the argument passed to the first invocation of that method.  Every time the body of the `while` loop is executed, it sets `entry` to a new value, and when the loop cycles you pass that new, unchecked, value to `tree.parent()`.  Indeed, each new value of `entry` is closer to the root than the previous one, because the whole point is to move up the tree from child to parent, i.e. toward the root.  It is entirely likely that sometimes this procedure will reach the root, and that's more likely the fewer elements are already in the tree.

One way to solve this would be to move the root-check into the `while` condition:

```
while (!entry.equals(tree.root())
        && entry.element().compareTo(tree.parent(entry).element()) < 0) {
    // ...
}
```

In that case, of course, you do not need the current one-time check that you perform outside the loop.

Comment: Ah yes, that never crossed my mind. That all makes perfect sense, and it appears that everything is working as it should now. Thank you

Comment: However, it seems the heap isn't being ordered. When I add elements into the heap and then print the state of the heap, it is ordered in the same fashion in which I inserted the elements into it. Also, no matter what elements I add into the heap - if I print the value of the root after each insertion, it is always the value of the first element I inserted (which makes no sense to me as before it was throwing the exception when the newly inserted element was swapped into the root position). See my original post where I will add the 'toString()' method

Comment: @KOB, that additional problem is not the subject of this question, but I nevertheless observe that although your `add()` method traverses the tree from leaf toward root, it does not appear to do anything that reorders any nodes.  In particular, code such as `entry = parent` does not do so -- it just changes which node local variable `entry` refers to.  It is possible that as you go, you want also to swap the contents of the `Position`s, but that's speculative on my part.

Comment: You explained that all very well. I changed it up to swap the values instead and it's all working as it should now. Thank you